# How to do an inverse zip operation

Tags: python

I can use zip to get a dictionary like so:

```
l1 = ['Director', 'peter jackson']
l2 = [u'Title', u'Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers']
dict(zip(l1,l2))
```

How would I get the same dict with the following two structures?

```
l1 = ['Director', 'Title']
l2 = [u'peter jackson', u'Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers']
```

Comment: Are you sure `dict(zip(l1, l2))` does what you want in the first case? It looks more appropriate for the second.

Comment: First snipped gives `{'Director': u'Title', 'peter jackson': u'Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers'}`. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, `dict(zip(l1,l2))` will give you the dict `{'Director':u'Title','peter jackson':u'Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers'}`.

In your second example, `dict(zip(l1,l2))` will give you what you probably want: `{'Director':u'peter jackson','Title':u'Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers'}`

Assuming you wanted the second one from both, you can just call `dict()` on the two lists from the first example:

```
dict([l1,l2])
```

You already know how to get that dict from the first example.

If you didn't make a mistake in your question, you can just `zip()` the two lists in your second example to get the two from your first example, then call `dict()` on those:

```
dict(zip(l1,l2))
```

Comment: I don't think `dict(l1, l2)` does what you want for the first example. Shouldn't that be `dict([l1, l2])`?

Comment: @user2357112 Ah, yeah, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you flipped the examples as the comments say, it looks like you're looking for:

```
l1 = ['Director', 'peter jackson']
l2 = [u'Title', u'Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers']
dict([l1, l2])
# {'Director': 'peter jackson', u'Title': u'Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers'}
```

`dict()` can also take a list of key value pairs.